# Why does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ diverge if $n \ln(n)$ is greater than $n$ for $n \geq 2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ diverge if $n \ln(n)$ is greater than $n$ for $n \geq 2$.  Shouldn't $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$ be comparable to a convergent p-series?  P-series converge for all $p > 1$ and if we try to imagine $n \ln(n)$ as a power of $n$ wouldn't the power be greater than 1?  What am I missing?

Comment: It's comparable to the p-series with $p=1$, which is not convergent. This doesn't prove it's non-convergent or convergent.

Comment: It's a “p-series” with a non-constant $p = 1 + \frac{\ln(\ln(n))}{\ln(n)}$.

Comment: @Dan it doesn't really make sense to call something that isn't a $p$-series a $p$-series—it's like saying that $f(x)=x^2$ is a "constant function" with a nonconstant constant....

Comment: To the OP: a similar question might be "Why does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2n}$ diverge if $2n$ is greater than $n$?" This might help point out what others have commented, that a series being smaller than a divergent series gives no information (nor would a series being larger than a convergent series).

Answer (score 5):

First off, you can't start the series $\ \sum_\limits{n}\frac{1}{n\ln n}\ $ at $\ n=1\ $ because $\ \ln 1=0\ $, so $\ \frac{1}{n\ln n}\ $ is undefined for $\ n=1\ $.

The series $\ \sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln n}\ $, however, is *not* comparable to a $\ p$-series for any $\ p>2\ $ because $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^p}{n\ln n}=\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{\ln n}=\infty\ $ for any such $\ p\ $.  Its divergence can be proved by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). The function $\ f(x)=\frac{1}{x\ln x}\ $ is monotone decreasing over the interval $\ [2,\infty)\ $, and
\begin{align}
\int_2^b\frac{1}{x\ln x}\,dx&=\ln\ln b-\ln\ln2\\
&\rightarrow\infty\ \text{ as }\ b\rightarrow\infty\ .
\end{align}
The integral test therefore tells us that $\ \sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln n}\ $ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f(x)=x\ln(x)$ is increasing for $x\ge 1$, so $g(x)=1/f(x)$ is decreasing. So, using the step functions known from Lebesgue or Riemann integrals, we get
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty g(n)
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_{n}^{n+1}g(n)\mathrm{d}x
\ge\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_{n}^{n+1}g(x)\mathrm{d}x
=\int_{2}^\infty g(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=[\ln(\ln(x))]_{x=2}^{\infty}=\infty.
\end{aligned}
Taking derivatives of $\ln^n(x)$ in the sense of an $n$-fold application of $\ln$, one can see that $(x\prod_{n=1}^\infty\ln^n(x))^{-1}$ marks the barrier, *intuitively* speaking. So, say $1/(x\ln(x)^{1+\varepsilon})$ (that's a power) is integrable, with anti-derivative $-1/(\varepsilon\ln(x)^{\varepsilon})$.